# Get a process ID

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I read a lot of questions about this argument, but I can't solve my issue.
I need to get a specific process ID and I wrote the following `test.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

PID=$(ps -ef | grep abc | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
echo $PID
```

Running this script I get two different PIDs if the `abc` process is not running and three different PIDs if the abc process is running.

If I run the

```
ps -ef | grep abc | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

command from shell I get the right result.

Modifing the `test.sh` script removing the last `awk` I noticed that the script prints the following output:

```
user1  22153 129551  0 15:56 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh
user1  22155  22153  0 15:56 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh
```

How is it possible and how can I ignore them?

Comment: I have to filter my output using grep commands.
Examples:
ps -ef | grep user | grep info1 | grep info2 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'

using it from shell works, but using it into a script it doesn't work.

Comment: I can ignore them using ... | grep -v $$


but how can I get only the first Pid in case of multiple results?

Comment: `grep "abc" | grep -v grep` can be done with `grep "[a]bc"`

Answer (score 3):

If you know exactly what is the process called, use `pidof`, otherwise, you can just use `pgrep`, it saves your `grep|grep|awk...`.

Note that, when you `ps|grep regex` or `pgrep regex` there could be multiple entries in your result.

Comment: Using pgrep I can't filter my output as I'm using grep <info1> | grep <info2> | grep <info3> | .....

Comment: @smithi88 you can find out why there are entries even if your process didn't start right? you can print out the full info, remove the last awk pipe, E.g.

Comment: thanks I noticed a double output of the test.sh.  
user1  22153 129551  0 15:56 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh
user1  22155  22153  0 15:56 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh

Answer (score 2):

Do not use these tools, use the right tool meant for this, command `pidof` with the `POSIX` compatible `-s` flag which according to the `man` page says,

```
-s     Single shot - this instructs the program to only return one
       pid.
```

Using the above,

```
processID=$(pidof -s "abc")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use grep to filter my output. I don't know the name of the process and I use a keywords in my grep commands.

Comment: @smithi88: Your requirement is not clear. Can you explain a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big fan of parsing the process table. It could be inaccurate. For the same reason as ["why not parse ls"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) You may want to look at the command [pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

My suggestion is doing

```
pgrep -u user1 abc
```